# CSS element opacity that does not affect transparency of its contents

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm trying to create a `<div>` that has an opacity of 60%. I want the content of that `<div>` to be clear and not transparent.

The `<div>` with the class `white_bg` should have a white background color with 60% transparency, but the text and the image inside that `<div>` should be clear and not transparent at all.

Is that possible?

Please note that the text in the paragraph with the class `main_content` will be dynamic and the height will always change, so I can't just set a width and a height for the `white_bg` class and use position absolute and place it right behind the paragraph.

#### HTML

```
<div class="white_bg">
    <h1 class="main_titles">Toon Boom Animate</h1>
    <h6 class="subtitles">The Most Reliable Flash Animator Companion</h6> 
                
    <p class="main_content">
    <img class="floatright" src="images/images.jpg" alt="" />
              text comes here
    </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better use semitransparent png as a background.

Comment: I think that this would be the perfect solution, cause the the content in that div is dynamic, if the content in that page was static it would've worked by setting the background an absolute position right behind the div i want without the need of changing the height of the div ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use css3's rgba() to set the background colour with an alpha value, and then use a transparent png for IE.

Answer (score 0):

either the semi-trans png as fantactuka mentions, or use position to place non-transparent content over your transparent div a la this blog post:

http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I am putting code for chrome , FF and IE.. the first code though works on ie9 and above but the second one is for below ei9

```
background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7F00FF00', EndColorStr='#7F00FF00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a semi transparent image, or apply this css to your element:

```
.white_bg {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For you `white_bg` class use this:

```
.white_bg
{
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Between those four properties, your bases should be pretty well covered for any major browser.

Comment: This will also render the contents of the `.white_bg` partially transparent.

Comment: opacity effects the background as well as the text.